# I'm trying to send some comands to spi.exe with subprocces

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

Here is my code:

---

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE

p = run(["C:/Users/user/Desktop/for_spi/spi.exe", 'f'], shell=True, stdout=PIPE,
        input='12\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\8\n9\n10\n11\n12\input.txt\noutput.dat\n', encoding='ascii')
print(p.returncode)
print(p.stdout)
print("File done")
```

---

and result:

---

```
Number of time scales:
timeScale1 
timeScale2 
timeScale3 
timeScale4 
timeScale5 
timeScale6 
timeScale7 
timeScale8 
timeScale9 
timeScale10 
timeScale11 
timeScale12 
Input file: 
Output file: could not open output file
```

---

The process should exit after the last command, but it cant open file

Comment: Try giving an absolute path to the output file

Comment: the program I run is located in the directory with the input files, after I specify the input file, it creates dat file

Comment: The output seems to indicate that the input file is empty (not found?). One possible reason is that the command runs in a different directory than what you expect. This could also explain why it fails to open the output file (missing permissions). Try giving absolute paths to both input and output files.

Comment: when i run the program(spi.exe) on the command line it works fine with no problem, I think problem is in the code

Comment: When you run it on the command line you probably do that inside the folder where the input file is located, right? That is not necessarily the case when running in Python. Have you tried giving the full path in the code?

Comment: Yes I have. I tried give the full path with name of file and output is same. But problem is same. when it runs in command line, no need to give full path. exe file located with txt files. it seems the program cant find file when im trying to run exe with code

Comment: Please update your question with the exact command you ran.